# CSS: prevent absolute image from extending into specific divs

Tags: css

Is there a way to prevent an absolutely placed image from extending into certain elements?

The reason: I allow my users to customize their websites by adding images. But it's possible for them to place the image in such a way that it covers the form buttons - then they can't remove it again.

```
#parent{
    position:relative;
}

#my_img {
    position:absolute; 
    # top, left can be anything
}


<div id = "parent">
    <img id = "my_img" src = "my_pic.jpg" >
</div>
<div id = "other_div">
    I always want to see this text regardless of my_img top and left
</div>
```

Comment: I do want it to be able to extend outside of the parent div, just not into the "other_div"

Comment: if `top,left,bottom and right` values can be anything then how are you going to predict the behaviour of that image? you may want to restrict that range..and keep your other content out of that range.

Comment: z-index only works for images, no?

Comment: @kleinfreund: That did it, thanks. I gave the form position:relative;z-index:10. (if you put it in an answer then I'll mark it correct.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determine in which order the elements of your html get laid out other than the document strucutre you need to position your element (relative, absolute or fixed) and give the element a `z-index` value.

Also you need to assign atleast top/bottom and left/right to positioned elements to prevent problems in older IE versions.

```
#other_div {
    position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    z-index: 1337;
}
```